# How do I specfiy a MongoHQ database when deploying Meteor app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to use my own MongoHQ database to use when deploying a Meteor app using `meteor deploy`. [The documentation explains how to do this when deploying and running on a machine I control](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying):

```
$ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

But the documentation seems a bit sparse on how to do this with `meteor deploy`. Is it possible?

EDIT: I tried following http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings and added a settings.json file and put in it:

```
{"MONGO_URL" : "mongodb://user:pass@mongohq.com:10000/mydatabase"}
```

then deployed with

`meteor deploy myappname.meteor.com --settings settings.json`

but the deployed version doesn't seen to be using my database

Comment: You need to decide where the web server for meteor will run.  MongoHQ can only fill the role of a DB Server.  I suspect that the deploy bundler doesn't include the MONGO_URL, so deploying to the Meteor infrastructure won't use the MongoHQ database.  But you should definitely ask the Meteor devs, and put in a request.

Comment: I want to deploy it with "meteor deploy", which I think deploys to their server. But I would like to use my own instance of MongoHQ instead of the default one.

Comment: I added a settings.json file and put in it: {"MONGO_URL" : "mongodb://user:pass@mongohq.com:10000/mydatabase"} then deployed with meteor `deploy myappname.meteor.com --settings settings.json` but the deployed version doesn't seen to be using my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up deploying to Heroku instead using the [buildpack](https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor). Then I could set the variables using the heroku configs.

Answer (score 2):

A quick scan of the codebase reveals this line in remote_collection_driver.js:

Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver = new Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver(process.env.MONGO_URL);

I'm sure if you hacked that to point where you wanted it, it would work. If that's too much of a kluge (for instance, if you plan on ever updating Meteor versions) you could experiment with trying to change Meteor._RemoteCollectionDriver or process.env.MONGO_URL early enough, from your own code (without hacking into Meteor's js directly). Good luck.