# Can Meteor be used with PaaS services?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Am I correct in the assumption that without access to the MongoDB server, there is not much point developing with Meteor?

Meteor is a great framework for building, packaging and deploy apps and sites.  From a development POV, the templating and responsive DB work make prototyping so much easier than most MVC's.

I understand that underneath the hood, websockets and DDP provide the realtime sync'ing magic which means that you need access to the MongoDB server, something you don't have with PaaS solutions like GoogleAppEngine, Parse or Kinvey.

So, for the backend developer, they don't derive much benefit from Meteor since they need to maintain the server stack and scalability issues.

Is there a path to create and deploy products with Meteor without having to build and maintain the backend infrastructure?  Heroku is still pretty close to the bone when it comes to managing infrastructure.

Wondering if there's a way to have CRUD operations through a REST driver that maps out to whatever PaaS you want and have the PaaS post log changes to a server that strictly handles websocket connections.  Basically, pass the CRUD operation to a PaaS and maintain your own websocket server/s.

Answer (score 0):

MeteorPedia has a page on deploying to PaaS: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Category:PaaS_providers

Recently, [Google AppEngine has added support for custom VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450321/why-is-javascript-node-js-not-on-google-app-engine/24427331#24427331).

You can also use [MongoHQ or similar for the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328704/how-do-i-specfiy-a-mongohq-database-when-deploying-meteor-app).

Comment: The PaaS providers listed look more like hosted databases or nodejs servers than the offerings of a GAP or Parse, they are just a bit friendlier than a Heroku.